# Create a logging object with std::stream interface

Tags: c++, ostream, streambuf

Internally we have a logging function with the interface `OurLog(const char *)`. I'd like to be able to use it with an interface similar to `std::ostringstream`. In other words, I'd love to have an adaptor object so I can write:

```
 logging_class log;
 log << "There are " << num_lights << " lights\n";
```

And this call `OurLog()` as necessary to write the message to the log.

It looks like making buffer class derived from `std::streambuf` is the right way to go; how does one go about this? What functions need to be implemented?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to implement `operator<<` for you class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple example in the libstdc++ documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/streambufs.html).

```
class LoggingBuffer : public std::streambuf {
protected:
    virtual int_type overflow (int_type c) {
        if (c != EOF) {
            char msg[2] = {static_cast<char>(c), 0};
            OurLog(msg);
        }
        return c;
    }
};

class Logger : public std::ostream {
    LoggingBuffer logging_buffer;
public:
    Logger() : logging_buffer(), std::ostream(&logging_buffer) {}

};

extern Logger log; //instantiated in a cpp file for global use
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look very performant, since it requires a function call for every single character. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: That's the general approach. There are other virtual functions in `std::streambuf` that you can override. Start by reading some [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf).

Answer (score 3):

If you want each line

```
log << "There are " << num_lights << " lights\n";
```

resulting in a call to your `OurLog(const char *)` then this toy example might help to get started:

```
struct toy_logger {
    std::stringstream data;
    ~toy_logger() { OurLog(data.c_str()); }
    template <typename T> operator<<(const T& t) { data << t; }
};
```

with only a minor difference in using it:

```
toy_logger() << "There are " << num_lights << " lights\n";
        //^ create temporary that will get its destructor called at the end of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like that. Depending on your requirements (particular to when flushing is required) there are some different approaches.

A very simple way is to simply inherit std::stringstream (and then exploit copy elision/RVO if you need an easier factory function for example). This will then write when object goes out of scope.

```
class LogStream : public std::ostringstream
{
public:
  LogStream(){}

  ~LogStream()
  {
        log(str());
  }
};
```

With the streambuf approach, you basic need is to just override sync() (and possible the destructor as well).

```
  virtual int sync() override {
    ::log(str());
    str("");//empty buffer
    return 0;//success
  }
```

Then instantiate std::ostream with your streambuf. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you need more info / details, perhaps with the streambuf approach (?), don't hessitate to ask.